# OpenGL Sphere not showing

Tags: opengl, glut, glfw, freeglut

The screenshot below shows the desired result.

[image: Desired result]

below is the actual result

[image]

I used the glutWireSphere API for drawing my sphere, however, it is not showing.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

const int RED_COLOR[3] =    {255,  0,  0};
const int GREEN_COLOR[3] =  {  0,  0,  255};

// color to draw in
void setDrawColor(const int rgb[3]) {
    float d = 255.0; // d = max value in an rgb color spectrum
    glColor3f(rgb[0]/d, rgb[1]/d, rgb[2]/d); // set draw color R=x/255 G=y/255 B=z/255 where x,y,z are values in rgb channel respectively
}

void drawPlane() {
    GLfloat A[3] = { -1, 0,  1 };
    GLfloat B[3] = { 1,  0,  1 };
    GLfloat C[3] = { 1,  0, -1 };
    GLfloat D[3] = { -1, 0, -1 };

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3fv(A);
        glVertex3fv(B);
        glVertex3fv(C);
        glVertex3fv(D);
    glEnd();
}

GLfloat CamX = 0, CamY = 2, CamZ = 2;
// Display Call Back
void draw() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear all drawings in buffer
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(CamX, CamY, CamZ, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    drawPlane();
    setDrawColor(GREEN_COLOR);              //  sets the drawing color to GREEN 
    glutWireSphere(0.2, 20, 20);
    glutSwapBuffers();// Render Now i.e convert Buffer to Picture
    return;
}

// Initialization
void initialize()
{
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f); // Set Background Color
    setDrawColor(RED_COLOR);              //  sets the drawing color to red 
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);             // enable viewing the 3d
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);         // change to perspective projection
    glLoadIdentity();                       // what does this do?
    glFrustum(-1, 1, -1, 1, 2, 10);         // what does this do?
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);             // what does this do?

}

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv); // Initialize GLUT
    int x = 512, y = 512;  // x and y value
    glutInitWindowPosition(
        (int)(glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH) - x) / 2,
        (int)(glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT) - y) / 2);              // Position the window's center
    glutInitWindowSize(x, y);                                     // Set the window's initial width & height
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);     // initialise the buffers needed. double buff, one for RGB color the other for x,y, z
    glutCreateWindow("3D Bowling Game");                          // Create a window with the given title
    initialize();                                   // Custom initialisation    
    glutDisplayFunc(draw);                          // Register display callback handler for window re-paint    
    glutMainLoop();                                 // Enter the event-processing loop

    return 0;
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, it works fine for me. There is a blue (`{ 0, 0, 255}` is blue) wireframe sphere in the center of the plane.

Comment: Thanks. the problem was that i did not change the drawing color. how do position this pls

Comment: You have to [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) the sphere. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial. Start reading!

Comment: Thanks, will do @Rabbid76. Could you recommend something